# How do I move text away from the top of a form box?

Tags: html, css

All I want to do is drop a piece of text in a form down from the top of the form so it isn't sitting right there at the top, I tried to use `padding-top`to move it down but it did nothing so is there another way to move it down? Here is my code,

```html
 
    <html>
    <style> 
    #form{float: left;
      position: relative;
      left: 37%;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color:3px black;
      width: 250px;}
    dt1{font-family: helvetica;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-left:37px;
    }

    dt2{font-family: helvetica;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-left:37px;}

    dt3{font-family: helvetica;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-left:37px;}

    dt4{font-family: helvetica;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-left:37px;}

    dt5{font-family: helvetica;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-left:37px;}

    dt6{color:red;
 padding-left: 37px;}

    #submit{background-color: white;
            float: left;
        position: relative;
        left: 33%;
            color: black;
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; <!-- login button-->}
    #submit:hover{background-color: #000000;
       color: white;
            border: 1px solid white;}
    </style>
    <form method="post" id="form">
 <d1>
  <dt1>Choose a Username:</dt1>
  <dd><input name="username" type="text" id="username"></dd>

  <dt2>Enter your Email:</dt2>
  <dd><input name="email" type="text" id="email"></dd>

  <dt3>Choose a Display Name:</dt3>
  <dd><input name="display_name" type="text" id="displayname"></dd>

  <dt4>Choose your Password:</dt4>
  <dd><input name="password1" type="password" id="password1"></dd>
  <dt5>Confirm Password:</dt5>
  <dd><input name="password2" type="password" id="password2"></dd>

  <dt6><%= @error_message %></dt6>
 </d1>
 <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Submit"></p>
    </form>
    </html>
```

Comment: can you add more info?? like view and text id or class? then it would be easier to understand your prob

Comment: set padding to the `form` [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urfc89dn/)

Answer (score 1):

```html
 
    <html>
    <style> 
    #form{float: left;
      position: relative;
      left: 37%;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color:3px black;
      width: 250px;
      padding:30px 0px;  
}
    dt1{font-family: helvetica;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-left:37px;
    }

    dt2{font-family: helvetica;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-left:37px;}

    dt3{font-family: helvetica;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-left:37px;}

    dt4{font-family: helvetica;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-left:37px;}

    dt5{font-family: helvetica;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-left:37px;}

    dt6{color:red;
 padding-left: 37px;}

    #submit{background-color: white;
            float: left;
        position: relative;
        left: 33%;
            color: black;
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; <!-- login button-->}
    #submit:hover{background-color: #000000;
       color: white;
            border: 1px solid white;}
    </style>
    <form method="post" id="form">
 <d1>
  <dt1>Choose a Username:</dt1>
  <dd><input name="username" type="text" id="username"></dd>

  <dt2>Enter your Email:</dt2>
  <dd><input name="email" type="text" id="email"></dd>

  <dt3>Choose a Display Name:</dt3>
  <dd><input name="display_name" type="text" id="displayname"></dd>

  <dt4>Choose your Password:</dt4>
  <dd><input name="password1" type="password" id="password1"></dd>
  <dt5>Confirm Password:</dt5>
  <dd><input name="password2" type="password" id="password2"></dd>

  <dt6><%= @error_message %></dt6>
 </d1>
 <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Submit"></p>
    </form>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There were too many mistakes to keep track of so I'll touch upon the blatant mistakes:

|**Wrong**|~~~~~~~~~~|**Right**|

`<d1...` ~~~~~~~~~~ `<dl...`

`<dt2...6` ~~~~~~~~~ `<dt...`

No `<head>` ~~~~~~~~ `<head>...</head>` at top

No `<body>` ~~~~~~~~ `<body>...</body>` after the head

`dt1....dt6`   ~~~~~~~~ `.d1` to `.d6` those are a classes in `<style>`

If you have the fundamental knowledge of HTML/CSS, then a simple thing is rarely an issue.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #form {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      padding: 25px 0 15px;
      left: 37%;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: 3px black;
      width: 250px;
    }
    .d1,
    .d2,
    .d3,
    .d4,
    .d5 {
      font-family: helvetica;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-left: 37px;
    }
    .d6 {
      color: red;
      padding-left: 37px;
    }
    #submit {
      background-color: white;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      left: 53%;
      color: black;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #submit:hover {
      background-color: #000000;
      color: white;
      border: 1px solid white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" id="form">
    <dl>
      <dt class='d1'>Choose a Username:</dt>
      <dd>
        <input name="username" type="text" id="username">
      </dd>
      <dt class='d2'>Enter your Email:</dt>
      <dd>
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email">
      </dd>
      <dt class='d3'>Choose a Display Name:</dt>
      <dd>
        <input name="display_name" type="text" id="displayname">
      </dd>
      <dt class='d4'>Choose your Password:</dt>
      <dd>
        <input name="password1" type="password" id="password1">
      </dd>
      <dt class='d5'>Confirm Password:</dt>
      <dd>
        <input name="password2" type="password" id="password2">
      </dd>
      <dd class='d6'></dd>
    </dl>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" id="submit">
    </p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by clearing some points:

The correct HTML tag is [**`<dl>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl)(D and L) **not** `<d1>` (D and 1).

> The HTML `<dl>` element (or HTML Description List Element) encloses a
>   list of pairs of terms and descriptions. Common uses for this element
>   are to implement a glossary or to display metadata (a list of
>   key-value pairs).

The [**description list**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/dl.html#description-list) element can contain:

- [**`<dt>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dt)

> The HTML `<dt>` element (or HTML Definition Term Element) identifies a
>   term in a definition list. This element can occur only as a child
>   element of a . It is usually followed by a  element; however,
>   multiple  elements in a row indicate several terms that are all
>   defined by the immediate next  element.

- [**`<dd>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dd)

> The HTML `<dd>` element (HTML Description Element) indicates the
>   description of a term in a description list () element. This
>   element can occur only as a child element of a description list and it
>   must follow a  element.

---

The `padding` that was set was not working because the unrecognized HTML tags were displaying as `inline`. You can read [**this**](http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/) to have an idea of what was going on.

---

Correcting the tags will get you were you want. We will add a padding to the first `<dt>` element, but this would be better if you add `padding` to the `form` element and not to its children.

```css
#form {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 37%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: 3px black;
  width: 250px;
}
dt {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 37px;
}
dt:first-of-type {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
dt:last-of-type {
  color: red;
}
#submit {
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 33%;
  color: black;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  <!-- login button-->
}
#submit:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="form">
  <d1>
    <dt>Choose a Username:</dt>
    <dd>
      <input name="username" type="text" id="username">
    </dd>

    <dt>Enter your Email:</dt>
    <dd>
      <input name="email" type="text" id="email">
    </dd>

    <dt>Choose a Display Name:</dt>
    <dd>
      <input name="display_name" type="text" id="displayname">
    </dd>

    <dt>Choose your Password:</dt>
    <dd>
      <input name="password1" type="password" id="password1">
    </dd>
    <dt>Confirm Password:</dt>
    <dd>
      <input name="password2" type="password" id="password2">
    </dd>
    <dt>
      @ error_message
    </dt>
  </d1>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
  </p>
</form>
```